# POST for data from RESTful API returns valid string when using CURL, but "decoding failed" when using fetch

Tags: javascript, json, curl, fetch-api

I have a simple expressjs proxy server relaying requests to a RESTful API and relaying the responses from that API back. If I use CURL to access it, like so:

```sh
curl -s "http://localhost:3000/api/findOne" \
  -X POST \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "Accept: application/json" \
  -d '{ /* request body */ }'
```

then I get valid JSON back to STDOUT.

But if I try to `fetch` it from the JavaScript front end like this:

```js
fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/findOne", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json", Accept: "application/json" },
  body: JSON.stringify(/* request body */),
})
  .then((res) => res.json()) // .text() doesn't work either!
  .then((res) => console.log(res))
  .catch((e) => e);
```

then I get this error returned from the catch block:

[image]

The worst part is, I have the proxy server printing out the requests it's receiving and the requests it produces to pull from the actual RESTful API, and I did a diff between the output it produces when the curl call is made, and the output it produces when the fetch call is made, and they're *identical*, character for character. Which means that the proxy server is doing the exact same thing each time, there's just something wrong with fetch that makes it unable to parse the result, ***even as plain text***, which is bizarre.

I haven't been able to find anything on the internet about this at all, can someone clue me in? Thanks. I'm a bit rusty with my web development skills (been out of the loop for a couple years).

**Edit**: Okay, so I've gotten a little further along: it seems that what's happening is that the output I'm getting from the proxy server is truncated, like, it just stops in the middle of the output stream, compared to the raw output from the API endpoint. Maybe that's making it impossible to decode? Even then, it should be decodable as text though, since curl does it, yet it seems JavaScript can't do that. Also, the decoding error happens even on outputs from the proxy server that *don't* at least visibly truncate. Here's the (slightly stripped down) server code:

```js
import express, { Express, Request, Response } from 'express';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import cors from 'cors';

dotenv.config();

const app: Express = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const apikey = ...;
const pathsToProxy = '/api/';
const MONGODB_URL = ...;

const corsOption = {
    credentials: true,
    origin: ['http://localhost:8080', 'http://localhost:3000'],
};

app.use(cors());

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.all('/api/*', async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    const url = req.url.replace(pathsToProxy, MONGODB_URL);

    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.set('Content-Type', req.get('content-type') || 'application/json');
    headers.set('Accept', req.get('accept') || 'application/json');
    headers.set('apiKey', apikey!);

    const mongoReq = {
        method: req.method,
        headers: headers,
        body: ['PUT', 'POST'].includes(req.method)
            ? JSON.stringify(req.body)
            : undefined,
    };
    try {
        const mongoRes = await fetch(url, mongoReq);
        mongoRes.body?.pipeTo(
            new WritableStream({
                start() {
                    res.statusCode = mongoRes.status;
                    mongoRes.headers.forEach((v, n) => res.setHeader(n, v));
                },
                write(chunk) {
                    res.write(chunk);
                },
                close() {
                    res.end();
                },
            })
        );
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        res.status(500).send(e);
    }
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`[server]: Server is running at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

I don't see anything obvious here that would lead to truncated output.

Comment: _"the output I'm getting from the proxy server"_... what proxy server?

Comment: I can put the code here if that would help. I just didnt want to overload the question if there was an obvious answer.

Comment: Since You're chunking response using `res.write(chunk);`  I have  doubts that You return proper JSON. It may look like proper json in output, but better I want to see screenshot or output of curl request from terminal.

Comment: Also I don't understand reason why You try to pipeTo instead of calling: `responseBody = await mongoRes.json();`

Comment: Manually rolling your own proxy seems a waste of effort when there already exists robust solutions https://github.com/http-party/node-http-proxy/blob/master/README.md

Comment: @Phil seems like it's not proxy, but api service which takes data from db, cause api key and etc is being passed in headers.

Comment: @num8er the proxy I linked to can inject headers. There's also `express-http-proxy` which is just as capable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply call `.json()` on response object to get proper body.

I don't see useful reason to chunk data which is returned as whole json from mongodb proxy api.

Solution is following:

```
     try {
        const mongoRes = await fetch(url, mongoReq);

        const status = mongoRes.status;
        const body = await mongoRes.json();
        
        // I don't recommend to resend headers
        // since it may return different 
        // content-length, content-encoding and etc. fields
        // which may be incorrect behavior
        // I'm commenting it in my answer,
        // but if it's necessary, 
        // then better extract only needed headers
        //
        // res.set({
        //   ...mongoRes.headers,
        // });

        res
          .status(mongoRes.status)
          .json(body);
     }
     catch (error) {
         console.error(error);
         res
           .status(500)
           .json({
             message: error.message,
           });
     }
```

P.S. "valid string" returned from CURL does not mean that it's valid json.

Comment: Thank you, I'll give this a shot! Re the PS, yeah, a valid string is definitely not necessarily valid json, but I did also try parsing out just a string from the fetch response on the front end since i knew i was at least getting a valid string, and that didnt work either, indicating a deeper problem, so that's what I was trying to get at.

Comment: I didn't try this approach initially because I literally have never touched Express JS before and have no idea what I'm doing LMAO, I usually program totally unrelated things

Comment: Hallelujah, this works! I initially felt fine doing the streaming solution because I figured it'd be better to pass the response from the rest api server to the client as I got it / was able to parse it, instead of waiting for it all to arrive at the proxy and then sending it all to the front end, since that's a bottleneck, but --- premature optimizations!

Comment: @AlexisPurslane data is already flushed from api server, chunking is needed when it's being read from source or written to destination as packets of data. In example: outputting binary file, chunking output of mp3 file or video file. But json responses should not be chunked, cause json is complete structure with start and end characters, correct commas and etc.

Comment: got it. I assumed it'd be fine because eventually all the chunks would arrive, but apparently that's not how it works. This is a good learning experience, thank you!